# Why does inserting a std::basic_streambuf* to an ostream insert the buffer content?

Tags: c++, iostream

Take this simple example program:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  using namespace std;
  fstream infile("main.cpp");
  basic_streambuf<char> *buf = infile.rdbuf();
  cout << static_cast<void *> (buf) << endl;
  cout << buf;
}
```

In order to print the actual address of the `basic_streambuf<>` object I had to explicitly cast it to a `void *`. So the main question is, why does C++ treat `basic_streambuf<>` like it's some kind of `const char *`? Is there some kind of implicit conversion happening or what kind of black voodoo is this?

Checking the usual online references like [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) and [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) does not show that `std::basic_streambuf` provides any public conversion operators. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: On cppreference, this is overload 8 of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

`ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );`

`Retrieves as many characters as possible from the input sequence controlled by the stream buffer object pointed by sb (if any) and inserts them into the stream, until either the input sequence is exhausted or the function fails to insert into the stream.`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/

`It is an instantiation of basic_streambuf with the following template parameters: charT = char`